# background image to cover whole page

Tags: css

**I want to set responsive image as  background for my whole page.**

**This is my CSS Code**

```css
body
        {
        background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Example.jpg'); 
        background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        }
```

```html
<body>


</body>
```

**But i am having issue when I open my page in small Screen. It don't display as it should be. 

Please help me to fix this.**

Comment: You can use a small, cut down version of large image for small screens

Comment: Use contain instead of cover?

Comment: Give width to 100%

Comment: no its not working

Comment: Why didnt you use img tag?

Comment: I am not use img tag use as background-image css property

Comment: the solution of this question is that use media query and change image as per different size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In large screen it should be ...**

```
background-size:cover
```

**and in small screen (media query)**

```
background-size:contain;
```

**also**

```
background-position:center
```

**Also if you could show us in JSfiddle it would be easy to fix.**

```css
body
        {
        background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Example.jpg'); 

        background-size: cover;
        background-size: contain;
        background-position: center;
        }
```

```html
<body>

</body>
```

Comment: [link] (http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-full/) I want to set my image like this

Comment: in this JSFiddel when device is small it will take only center view that is not right. I want the whole image as small device too

Comment: you need to explain/show what you want, a fiddle would be good to show exact issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115189/discussion-between-sanjeev-k-and-shivani).

Answer (score 1):

At first you should clear your style, there is no need of prefix for background-size anymore, also "background-repeat" property can be "repeat" or "no-repeat", Not both at the same time. Also you would like to set your background position. So your css code should look like:

```
background-image: url('../images/img1.jpg'); 
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
```

After that you have to set this style to the correct element, for your case you can use `body` tag.
So your final code should look like:

```
body { 
     background-image: url('../images/img1.jpg'); 
     background-repeat: no-repeat; 
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: center center;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is working for me :-

```
body {
  background-image: url(images/background-photo.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color:#464646;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe try making the width and height 100%

Comment: when i set widh:100% and height:100% then my image was cut. I want full image as per as it is

Comment: try using   background-size: 100% 100%;

Answer (score -1):

You Should Have To Try @Media Css Query IT Will Works For You

Comment: you can better understand from here [link]http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score -1):

You need to use background: instead of background-image:

```
 background: url(../images/img1.jpg)no-repeat center;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: seems makes no any difference

Comment: The background property just enables you to write specific properties in shorthand.

Answer (score -1):

Try the jquery-backstretch plugin. https://github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch